# Using "link_to" in a button to link to a different page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have my button link to a different page in this bootstrap setup. The file is located in "static_pages" and is called "register.html.erb". It also has a named route called "register_path". How do I make my button link there?

I've tried this using "a href" and it doesn't work. I assumed it's better to use "link_to" but I didn't know how to do that.

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="static_pages/register">Sign Up</a></p>
```

Comment: So, what is the real problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Register Page", register_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is going to make your life a lot easier.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up", register_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
```